# Multiple checkbox MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, checkbox

Preciso criar uma lista com habilidades de tecnologia "skills"
nessa lista "skills" eu possa selecionar quantas habilidades for necessária, tipo um"checklistbox" porem ao selecionar as opções, precisa encaminhar os dados para o banco de dados em SQL a quantidade de "skills" selecionadas com seu "id"

Tecnologias: (Múltiplos com CTRL)
                 @Html.CheckboxList("SkillId", null, new { @class = "form-control" })

Função Multiplos não está funcionando ao clicar nas "skills" me fornece apenas a primeira habilidade em que eu cliquei.

Answer (score 0):

No controller deve ter uma ação para receber multiplos valores, por exemplo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(List<ListItem> items)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            ViewBag.Message += string.Format("Item selecionado:" + item);
        }
    }
    return View(items);
}
```

Outra alternativa seria criar uma função e passar uma lista de ids para a controller via ajax.
por exemplo:

```
  $(function () {  
        $('#submit').click(function () {
            var items = [];
            $('input:checked').each(function () {
                items .push($(this).attr("value"));
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action()',
                dataType: "html",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ SelectedItems: items  }),
                success:
                    function (data) { }

            });
    });

});
```